# How do you make a spritesheet image wider in pygame?

Tags: pygame, pycharm, python-3.7

I am making a platformer game in pygame. I want to have a floor on the bottom of the level that the player can walk on. In my Floor class, I used a grass image and made it much longer. However, when I run the program, the image stays the same. Can someone fix this? Is it something in my code?

```py
import pygame
from spritesheet_functions import SpriteSheet

GRASS = (648, 0, 70, 70)

   class Floor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

        def __init__(self, sprite_sheet_data):

            super().__init__()

            sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet('tiles_spritesheet.png')

            self.image=sprite_sheet.get_image(sprite_sheet_data[0],

                                              sprite_sheet_data[1],

                                              sprite_sheet_data[2],

                                              sprite_sheet_data[3])

            self.floor = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, 
                                               (6000, 50))

            self.rect = self.floor.get_rect()


class Level(object):

    def __init__(self, player):

        self.floor_list = None

        self.floor_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def update(self):
        self.floor_list.update()

    def draw(self, screen):
        self.floor_list.draw(screen)


class Level01(Level):

    def __init__(self, player):

        Level.__init__(self, player)

        level_floor = [[floors.GRASS, 0, 550]]

        for ground in level_floor:
            floor = floors.Floor(ground[0])
            floor.rect.x = ground[1]
            floor.rect.y = ground[2]
            floor.player = self.player
            self.floor_list.add(floor)
```

Comment: where do you draw it ? Probably you draw `self.image`. You should keep original image in different variables and use `self.image` only to keep current displayed image (ie. rescaled)

Comment: Where do I do that?

Comment: I draw it all in another file. That works, but the image isn't transformed.

Comment: if you keep `Sprites` in `Group` and run `group.draw()` then it use `self.image`, `self.rect` to display it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, but the image isn't transformed to how I want it.

Comment: as I said - if you draw `self.image` (in another file) then you have to assign rescalled image to `self.image` and keep original image in different variable - ie. `self.original_image`

Comment: The self.floor is supposed to do that, but it doesn't

Comment: if you draw `self.image` then it will NOT draw `self.floor`. What variable do you use in another file ?

Comment: I added the levels in the code

Comment: Now there is a floor, but everything is moving along with it

Comment: you keep it in group - `self.floor_list = pygame.sprite.Group()` and later you use this group to draw it - `self.floor_list.draw(screen)` - and group always uses `self.image, self.rect` to draw element - and you can't change it (doc: [Group.draw](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw)). So you have to assign rescaled image to `self.image`

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: how do you assign rescaled image to self.image ? `self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (6000, 50))`

Comment: No I did self.floor = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (6000, 50)).

Comment: Should I change self.floor to self.image?

Comment: Yay, the floor works!

Comment: but Group DOESN"T USE VARIABLE `self.floor` to display it.

Comment: Yes, I changed that sorry

Comment: However, now my player is moving with one block throughout the whole map for some reason

Comment: where is Player code ? do you change image in `self.image` in every loop ?

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) is a methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`. `pygame.sprite.Group.draw()` uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects - you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

You must reassign the scaled image to the attribute `image`:

<s>`self.floor = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (6000, 50))`</s>

```py
self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (6000, 50))
```